# Upload php script problems

Tags: php, file-upload, expression-web

Using Expression Web, want to upload images to my web pages, not getting error messages even though written in script.  Set the upload folder to share with everyone.  `php.ini` is set to `file_uploads=on;upload_max_size=128M`.  On firefox the script times out and on IE "Internet Explorer can not display page."

I have been searching for answers for weeks. Every other script I have tried works even though I am a novice at php.  This upload thing has gotten me scratching my head. Most recent upload script attempt:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // Check for an uploaded file:
    if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {

        // Validate the type. Should be JPEG or PNG.
        $allowed = array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png');
        if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)) {

            $target_path = "C:/uploads/";
            $name=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
            $error=$_FILES['upload']['error'];
            $tmp_name=$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];

            if($error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

               if($_FILES['upload']['size']>0){

               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path.$name); 

            print ("The file ".$name." has been uploaded.\n");

             } else{

             print ("There was an error uploading the file, please try again!\n");

             }

             }elseif ($error==UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {

             print("No files specified.\n");

             }else{

             print("Upload failed.\n");

             }
             print("\n");


        }//End of !in_array IF.

    } // End of isset($_FILES['upload']) IF.


} // End of the submitted conditional.
?>

<div>
  <form action="photogallery.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"  value="524288" />
  <p><b>File:</b><input name="upload" type="file" /></p>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="TRUE" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to upload images into upload folder in my directory and then display on my web page.  I have put images into the folder manually and they will show on my webpage via a link but it wont work using these scripts.  My site is not live it is in developement and I am using XAMPP and Microsoft development Server.

Comment: `if (question.title.match(/!{2,}/)) { question.close() }`

Comment: it's strange that it works..I just copy pasted the entire code and name it `photogallery.php`, created the upload directory and tried uploading. I'm using WAMP (php 5.3.5), though.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is hard to tell. But there are a few points to mention on your script (typical upload script problems):

- The `['name']` constanct *could* be empty, which would explain an upload error.
- But it could also be tampered with, and contain things like `"../Windows/System.ini"`, which wouldn't be so good for your script since you use it unfiltered as output filename.
- The MIME `['type']` is likewise unreliable. But that's likely not the problem here. At the very least use `strtolower()` on it instead of listing multiple MIME alternatives.
- Lastly enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` which will tell you if move_upload_file() permission issues are the problem.

I would suggest that you start with a simple

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "C:/uploads/test.1");
```

And then *gradually* extend it with your other conditions to find the cause of your upload issue.